# Gridview on Linkbutton click, Pass complete GridRow information to the next page? What are best ways to do this?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have Gridview that has 6 other BoundField Columns and one Linkbutton column.
I want to pass all the Row information to the next page when users click on LinkButton.

What are the best ways to do this?
If we pass it as QueryString, it is going to be Too long.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `LinkButton` Column  itself to your advantage.

The idea is to send the [**`RowIndex`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.rowindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the [**`GridViewRow`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in [**`PostBackUrl`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.postbackurl%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of LinkButton as a QueryString Parameter.

Use the [**`Container.DataItemIndex`**](http://somedotnettips.blogspot.in/2010/01/blog-containerdataitemindex.html) which represents the Index of the Row.

At the Next/Destination page , get the RowIndex from QueryString to get the GridViewRow and then read the Column values.

Step 1.) The markup corresponding to LinkButton should be as below:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDetails" runat="server" Text="Send Details"
              PostBackUrl='<%# "~/NextPage.aspx?RowIndex=" +
                            Container.DataItemIndex %>'>
          </asp:LinkButton>
      </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Step 2.) In the Page Load event of `NextPage.aspx`, get first the GridViewRow where LinkButton was clicked and then read the row values

Note that using the PostBackUrl property in essence makes a cross page postback and therefore you can use the property [**`Page.PreviousPage`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Page.PreviousPage != null)
    {
        int rowIndex = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["RowIndex"]);
        GridView GridView1 = (GridView)this.Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("GridView1");
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[rowIndex];

        //Since you use Bound Fields, use row.Cells[] to read values
        String Column_One_Value = row.Cells[0].Text;
        String Column_Two_Value = row.Cells[1].Text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

*Too long* is subjective, anyways, if you don't want to use `QueryString` you can use [Session Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), Session vars are kept across the web site

```
protected void gvUsers_PageIndexChanging(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["TheSelectedRow"] = ((Control)sender).Parent as GridViewRow; 
    // Your code to redirect 
}
```

or you can wrap them in **Properties**, to work better and *avoid* casting every time in different lines and spelling mistakes

```
public GridViewRow TheSelectedRow
{
    get { return Session["TheSelectedRow"] == null ? null : Session["TheSelectedRow"] as GridViewRow; }
    set { Session["TheSelectedRow"] = value; }
}
```

and then in your click event this

```
protected void gvUsers_PageIndexChanging(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TheSelectedRow = ((Control)sender).Parent as GridViewRow; 
    // Your code to redirect 
}
```